# Google Cloud Loadbalancer HTTPS only (or forward http to https)

Tags: http, ssl, https, gcloud

We are running our infrastructure with different content servers in the Google cloud.

We are using HTTP load balancing and forward traffic to our instance groups.

At the moment we are struggling to accept HTTP but force/forward to HTTPS?

What is the best practice to do that?

Thank you in advance. :)

Leo
PS: we tried to use .htaccess rewrite on our loadbalanced (Apache) instances, but this does not work.

Comment: Your backend instances behind load balancer serving HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: at the moment both ...

Comment: sorry the loadbalancer is serving HTTP and HTTPS

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you are trying to setup HTTPS frontend with HTTP backends. If thats correct, you can achieve this setup with HTTPS load balancer.

Comment: sorry for the confusion:
- my loadbalancer accepts HTTP and HTTPS at the moment
- my backend accepts HTTS and HTTPS at the moment

I only want to allow HTTPS connections with the backend.
The idea was to "rewrite" incoming HTTP requests at the loadbalancer.

Any idea how that could work?

Comment: Currently, HTTP to HTTPS redirection (using SSL) has to be done by configuring the webserver. This feature is not available through HTTP/HTTPS load balancer. With that said, feel free to file a feature request on Compute Engine issue tracker (https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/list).

Comment: There is a feature request open now (https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?id=255) you can subscribe to it to get updates by clicking the star at the top.